# Give a Matrix $P \in M_{2,2}(\mathbb{C})$ with the following properties:

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

i) the Matrix P has only real elements

ii) 2+i is an eigenvalue of Matrix P

I got that the zeros has to be $(x-(2+i))(x-(2-i))$ which is equal to $(x-2)^2 -i^2$ so the characteristical polynom is equal to $x^2-4x+4+1 =x^2-4x+5$ how can I find the matrix of this characteristical polynom?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the zeros are $(x-(2+i))(x-(2-i))$ =

$$=((x-2)+i)((x-2)-i)$$
$$=(x-2)^2-i^2 = x^2-4x+4+1=x^2-4x+5$$

So we get that characteristical polynom has the factors $(2-x)(2-x)=x^2-2x-2x+4 +1$ which gives us the determinant:

\begin{vmatrix}
2-x & 1 \\ 
-1 & 2-x
\end{vmatrix}

the corresponding matrix is :\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
-1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

or the determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
2-x & -1 \\ 
1 & 2-x
\end{vmatrix}

the corresponding matrix is :\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1\\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 1):

If you find $A$ with eigenvalues $\pm i$, then $\alpha I+A$ has eigenvalues $\alpha \pm i$. Indeed,
$$ \det\bigl(( \alpha I+A )-\lambda I \bigr)=\det\bigl(A-( \lambda-\alpha)\,I\bigr).
$$
That is, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $\alpha I+A$ if and only if $\lambda-\alpha=i$.